# How to randomize float and percentage in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

How to randomize float (for opacity) and percentage (for position) in SASS?  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XZMXMM

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

For position I am only able to randomize by `px`, if I put `%` it doesn't work.

```
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  background: #333;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

@for $i from 0 to 15 {
  .parent .child:nth-child(#{$i}) {

     // Instead of px this should randomize by percent up to 100% (20%, 45%, 77%...)
     left: random(100) + px; 

     // This should randomize opacity (0.5, 0.7, 0.9, ...)
     opacity: 1;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following solution using the [`percentage`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#percentage-instance_method) function:

```
@for $i from 0 to 15 {
  .parent .child:nth-child(#{$i}) {

    //this should randomize by percent up to 100% (20%, 45%, 77%, ...)
    left: percentage(random(100) / 100);

    //this should randomize opacity (0.5, 0.7, 0.9, ...)
    opacity: random(10) / 10;
  }
}
```

You can also use the original answer without the [`percentage`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#percentage-instance_method) function:

```
@for $i from 0 to 15 {
  .parent .child:nth-child(#{$i}) {

    //this should randomize by percent up to 100% (20%, 45%, 77%, ...)
    left: random(100) / 100 * 100%;

    //this should randomize opacity (0.5, 0.7, 0.9, ...)
    opacity: random(10) / 10;
  }
}
```

You can find a [working demo on CodePen](https://codepen.io/sebastianbrosch/pen/NypvKJ/).